# How to convert DataView,DataRowView to Generic Typed Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, list, generics

Is there any possible method than looping, Enumerating the ICollection to convert them respectively to Typed List knowing the columns in the ICollection. I am using .net Framework 2.0, C#2.0. Expected answer would be something like this,a one liner

`List<Bills> bills = GetBills(DataView/DataRowView/ICollection);`

where `Bills` type would have `BillNumber, BillDate, BilledTo` as properties. The DataRowView/DataView would have corresponding Columns with records in them. Is there a factory build method that does the Job? If No any one liner to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you do it in one line using a LINQ Select with a lambda? Something along these lines....

```
List<Bills> bills = yourDataView.Rows.Select(t => new Bills() {BillNumber = t["BillNumber"], BillDate = t["BillDate"], BilledTo = t["BilledTo"]}).ToList();
```

Comment: Will not work as he's on the 2.0 framework so no Linq unfortunately.

Comment: Bah. didn't see that bit. Would be a simpler solution.

Comment: NET 2.0 so boo to Linq. darn if i had 3.5 would be so happier

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq Select to convert the DataView rows to a List of objects:

```
DataView yourDataView;

List<Bills> bills = yourDataView.ToTable().Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Select(r => new Bills() 
                    { 
                        BillNumber = r.Field<int>("BillNumber"), 
                        BillDate = r.Field<DateTime>("BillDate"), 
                        BilledTo = r["BilledTo"].ToString()                 
                    }).ToList();
```