# use LINQ for queries on BindingSource

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding

I want to use Linq for queries on Binding Source.

```
var myItems = ((IList<myObjectBinding>)myTableBindingSource.List).Where(some linq query);
```

This code gives the following error during runtime: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList

So, Is it possible to use Linq for queries on binding source? I want to use binding source objects elsewhere in the code.

Comment: You can check out the following approach: [DataView to generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276261/5913970)

Answer (score 3):

first you have to get all records from bindingSource.DataSource in a list like

```
var list = myBindingSource.List.OfType<yourmodel/class>();
```

than you can use query on this list like

```
var records = list.where(u => u.id == yourid).ToList();
```

Comment: Or simply write it as a single line....

var records = myBindingSource.List.OfType<yourmodel/class>().Where(u => u.id == yourid).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a converter and add your LINQ logic in the converter.

Comment: Would you please explain this method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to the generic version of IList using the Cast extension:

```
((IList)myTableBindingSource.List).Cast<myObjectBinding>().Where(some linq query);
```

DataView inherits from [System.Collections.IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx), but you are trying to cast to [System.Collections.Generic.IList](http://You%20need%20to%20cast%20to%20the%20generic%20version%20of%20IList%20using%20the%20Cast%20extension:%20%20%20%20%20%20((IList)myTableBindingSource.List).Cast%3CmyObjectBinding%3E().Where(some%20linq%20query);%20%20DataView%20inherits%20from%20[System.Collections.IList][1],%20but%20you%20are%20trying%20to%20cast%20to%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[System.Collections.Generic.IList%3CT%3E.][2]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx%20%20%20[2]:%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx).